# Eureka Client on my localhost can not register to localhost eureka server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, service-discovery

*I am currently at the beginner level*

eureka server on port 8761 is running properly,

but the service annotated with @EnableEurekaClient failed to register with the eureka server.
When I start the client service, it starts without any error but is not registering itself either.

This is my eureka server's application.properties

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=true
eureka.server.eviction-interval-timer-in-ms=60000
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=3000
spring.application.name=eurekaServer
```

And this is pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

eureka client's application.properties :

```
server.port=8799
spring.application.name=product
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

```
eureka client's pom.xml :

  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       
    </properties>

       <dependencies>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>

            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
       
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2022.0.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


</project>
```

Please help me figure out this issue.

Comment: post the error stack info, at least  wew should know  where the error you encounter.

Comment: When I start the client service, it starts without any error but is not registering itself either @Peng

Comment: Have your @EnableEurekaServer  tag your server application ? refer to  your config , there is no reason  that  the client  connection is failed